# iOS: When I try to get CLLocation by click, there is most of the time a "big" lag

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm first using the CoreLocation framework. I have a table and by button click a new location should be added and the distance to all entries in the table should be shown and updated all the time. That is why I have a BOOL saveNewLocation which is set to Yes when the button is clicked. Because the updates need to happen still all the time in the background, but when the button is clicked only a new entry is added.

At the moment I have this in my viewDidLoad:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    // Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.
    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And this is my delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;
    if(self.saveNewLocation){
       [PointOfInterest addPointOfInterest:newLocation withAddress:@"" andNotes:@"" inManagedObjectContext:self.cdh.context];
        self.saveNewLocation = NO;
    }
    [self updateAllDistances];
}
```

And this my button:

```
- (IBAction)addLocationClicked:(id)sender {
    self.saveNewLocation = YES;
}
```

But the problem at the moment is that when you click this button, there is sometimes a big lag and nothing happens. Sometimes immediately a new location is added. How can I avoid this lag and instantly add a new location by click?

Comment: When you use the Profiler in Xcode, where does it record the largest amount of time taken?

Comment: The method didUpdateLocation only runs when the location actually changes. Your button is then setting a bool. So it will only be saved the next time the location changes. That could be forever. You should be storing the location in a property and updating it when the method runs. Then when the button is pressed just use that property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time interval between update calls to the location manager delegate is variable, so the behavior you're experiencing is expected.

`CLLocationManager` has a property called `location` which returns the last known location of the user (or nil if you've never used the Location Manager in the app).

Instead of waiting for the LocationManager to update, grab the last known location of the user instead:

```
- (IBAction)addLocationClicked:(id)sender {
    CLLocation *location = self.locationManager.location;
    if (location && [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - location.timeStamp.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate < 60 * 10){
    //Do something with the location if the location manager returns a location within the last 10 minutes
    } else {
       self.saveNewLocation = YES;
    }
}
```

If the app has never asked for it's location, you may get nil, in which case you'll have to wait for the locationManager to update.  But otherwise, you can just grab the last known location.  You can also check whether the location was update recently by checking the timeStamp on the location object.

You also may want to set a state flag indicating that the app *should* wait for a location update when the location manager is first used.  When you first start up the LocationManager, you can't really know how up-to-date that location is.  But once the manager begins updating the delegate, you can be reasonably certain the `location` manager holds a fairly up-to-date location.

Comment: You can force a position update by stoping and restarting your location manager, in case you have `nil` and don't want to wait.

Comment: @Crazyrems The *only* time the LocationManager will return `nil` for `location` is if it's never been used in the app.  Even if you restart the app, the LocationManager will will return a value for `location`.  Thus, it never actually makes sense to restart the location manager.  If `location` returns `nil`, the location manager has not been started (or is waiting for it's first ever location). Per Apple Docs: `The value of this property is nil if no location data has ever been retrieved.`

Comment: You're right, that's only if the position is relatively old that you want to force an update.

Comment: Yeah, and in his code, the location manager is started as soon as the view loads.  So any time the user presses the button the location manager will already be running.  He just needs to decide whether he wants to wait or not for the next update.

Comment: In order to use this approach you should really check the timestamp and horizontal accuracy of the reading you get. When you first turn on the location manager the system will give you the last location it collected when the GPS was active, even if that was several days ago. It can be off by many kilometers. You probably don't want to accept an answer that's more than a few minutes old. It also pays to check the accuracy reading and reject location values that are too inaccurate. (How much error makes it "too inaccurate" is up to you.)